# Display Table Rows Within Row

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

What I am trying to achieve best described in the example diagram below, in a html table. My table works fine with data from a MySQL database but all the data is printed in rows, which is correct, however I am required to display the data in the format below and the same format in Excel. This avoids repeating similar data.

My SQL statement is this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE Date = '$DateToday' ORDER BY Airline ASC, Flight ASC, Name");
```

but I guess to achieve the desired display php would be more relevant than MySQL.

[image: Table Ecample]
So first the while loop....

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { $results = mysql_query("SELECT *      FROM Reservations WHERE Airline = '$Airline'");
$Count = mysql_num_rows($results);
if($Count > 1) // More then 1 passenger on same flight
{
  $iReservationID     = $row['ReservationID'];
  $iAirline           = strtoupper($row['Airline']);
  $iFlight            = strtoupper($row['Flight']);
  $iName              = strtoupper($row['Name']);
  $iName              = "<BR>".$iName;                        
} else {// NOT More then 1 passenger on same flight
    $ReservationID    = $row['ReservationID'];
    $Airline          = strtoupper($row['Airline']);
    $Flight           = strtoupper($row['Flight']);
    $Name             = strtoupper($row['Name']);                     
  } 
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>AIRLINE</td>";
    <td>FLIGHT#</td>";
    <td>PASSENGER</td>";
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>echo $Airline;</td>
    <td>echo $Flight;</td>
    <td>print "$Name<BR>$iName</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The table works fine with rows for each entry when there is only one passenger but it is duplicating the passenger names when nested.

`SELECT DISTINCT` doesn't do the trick either nor `SELECT FROM Reservations WHERE ReservationID <> $ReservationID`  - I have tried a second `WHILE` loop to refetch the data according to FLIGHT# but still not correct.

Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Inside loop you are applying where condition on Airline, what if you have same airline with different flight?

Comment: You are correct Vara and that would certainly happen. In that case I think a new row should be written that displays the AIRLINE name, (again) the different FLIGHT#, and the corresponding passenger names. I am trying the examples now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(Name SEPARATOR '<BR>') AS PasName FROM Reservations WHERE Date = '$DateToday' GROUP BY Airline,Flight ORDER BY Airline ASC, Flight ASC, Name");
echo "<table>
<tr>
    <td>AIRLINE</td>
    <td>FLIGHT#</td>
    <td>PASSENGER</td>
</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    //$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE Airline = '$Airline'");

    $ReservationID = $row['ReservationID'];
    $Airline = strtoupper($row['Airline']);
    $Flight = strtoupper($row['Flight']);
    $Name = strtoupper($row['PasName']);

    //$Count = mysql_num_rows($results);
    /*if ($Count > 1) { // More then 1 passenger on same flight
        $iName = "";
        while ($inrow = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
            $iName .= "<BR>".$inrow['Name'];
        }
    } else {// NOT More then 1 passenger on same flight
        // $ReservationID = $row['ReservationID'];
        // $Airline = strtoupper($row['Airline']);
        // $Flight = strtoupper($row['Flight']);
    }*/
    echo "<tr>
        <td>$Airline</td>
        <td>$Flight</td>
        <td>$Name</td>
    </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

But, I recommend you to fetch the multiple users within query only i.e replace this query

```
SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE Airline = '$Airline'
```

with

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name SEPARATOR '<BR>') FROM Reservations WHERE Airline = '$Airline' GROUP BY Airline,Flight
```

so that there is no need of inside loop for concating user names

Comment: Ok, so I have gone through this example but get the same results as my own example... that is AIRLINE and FLIGHT# being displayed on every row for each PASSENGER -  in fact the same results as using $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE Date = '$DateToday' ORDER BY Airline ASC, Flight, Name"); The hard part seems to be not duplicating AIRLINE name or FLIGHT # over and over... I'll be trying again.

Comment: Hi @Stray I have updated my answer, please check now

Comment: Hi @ Vara - YES - BRILLIANT - Printing the closing </tr></td> AFTER printing the results is the game changer. Also that select statement with SEPARATOR <BR> puts it together perfectly. This is excellent Vara. I think there will be many people who will like this format for displaying table data. Just one small point can I ask, can you edit your answer and remove the 'i' from the variables $ReservationID, $Airline, $Flight, etc. as I was only using that to differentiate. If anyone wants to copy my database example then Vara's solution works perfectly. Thank you so very much!

Comment: Thanks @StrayDog, you can accept my answer if it's useful

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE Date = '$DateToday' ORDER BY Airline ASC, Flight ASC, Name";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<table>
              <tr>
                <td>AIRLINE</td>
                <td>FLIGHT#</td>
                <td>PASSENGER</td>
              </tr>
          ";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>"+$row['ReservationID']+"</td>
                <td>"+strtoupper($row['Airline'])+"</td>
                <td>"+strtoupper($row['Flight'])+"</td>
                <td>"+MethodToFetchNameOfPassengersOfTheFlight(params)+"</td>
            </tr>";

    echo "</table>";
}
```

for the method

```
string MethodToFetchNameOfPassengersOfTheFlight(params){
    //write a query to fetch the name of the passenger of the flight
    $CustomerNames = "";
    //in for each loop do this
    foreach($name in $names)
        $CustomerNames += $name + "<br>";
    return strtoupper($CustomerNames);
}
```

First we show the details of the airlines. Then we find the passengers of the corresponding flight and append them in a string with breaks and then distplay them.